# CURL -X POST command - The specified file can not be found

Tags: curl, post, heroku, server, get

I am at the stage of building a project based on layouts for indoor location, I wanted to use visualization software from this site for the time of testing:

http://www.instructables.com/id/JARVAS-Indoor-Positioning-System/ **point 7 Set Up the Servers**

The HEROKU server used for these purposes was created by two new projects, one for the API second to the frontend, everything went according to the recommendations of the pro ...

but if you want to test the server by entering the command in the terminal

**curl -X POST ' dwmserwer.herokuapp.com/beacons ' -H 'Content-Type: application / json '-d' {"beacons": [{"id": "a", "location": [10, 0]}, {"id": "b", "location": [0, 10]}, {"id": "c", "location": [0, 0]}]} '**

I get a message

The specified file can not be found.

Can anyone help me start the server?

codes from the HEROKU server

https://megawrzuta.pl/download/40069906a83a9a10a336c36151fd5312.html

Comment: The curl command you posted looks wrong. It should probably be something like this:

   curl -X POST https://dwmserwer.herokuapp.com/beacons -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"beacons": [{"id": "a", "location": [10, 0]}, {"id": "b", "location": [0, 10]}, {"id": "c", "location": [0, 0]}]}'

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

The problem lies in the application code because each time you get the message:
"Application error"

Could you look at the source code? (it's not long)
https://megawrzuta.pl/download/40da0b0caae92f43d021025f464ccc21.html